# withTimeout not throwing TimeoutCancellationException after the specified time period

Tags: kotlin

A connection made to an endpoint that is not reachable, not because the endpoint doesn't exist, but because it's on a different network, so a network timeout error is expected, which can take more than 3 seconds (probably around 15). But the withTimeout is set to expire after 3 seconds. The exception is thrown but not for a very long time - way more than 3 seconds. What could be causing this?

```kotlin
try {
    withTimeout(3000) {
        var response = URL("http://192.168.10.10/getData").readText()
  
        // This line is never executed...
        var x = 0
    }
} catch (ex: IOException) {

} catch (ex: TimeoutCancellationException) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you're not calling a suspending function inside your `withTimeout` block. Consider the following two situations:

This causes timeout after 3 seconds:

```
withTimeout(3000) {
    delay(10000)
}
```

This runs for 10 seconds without a timeout:

```
withTimeout(3000) {
    Thread.sleep(10000)
}
```

This is because `Thread.sleep` is not a suspending function. You can get around this by wrapping it in `withContext`. The following times out after 3 seconds, as you intended:

```
withTimeout(3000) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { Thread.sleep(10000) }
}
```

However, `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` will run the block in a new thread, so although the coroutine times out, the thread will continue running. Thanks Tenfour04 for pointing this out.

Comment: It’s worth mentioning that the blocking function will still run to completion on one of the IO threads. It’s just that the coroutine that used `withTimeout` will continue without waiting for it.

Comment: I tried using your suggestion and wrapped it in a withContext(Dispatchers.IO) but timed out after 10 seconds and not the 3 seconds, so there is clearly something else preventing it.

Comment: It's probably due to what Tenfour04 said. The `Dispatchers.IO` thread that runs the non-suspending code remains alive for 10 seconds, so if you try this from the `main` function, the JVM will run until all current threads have completed, hence 10 seconds.